# Purpose of ( ) in sklearn.datasets?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

```
from sklearn.datasets import load_digits
data=load_digits
type(data)
```

type(data) returns "function"

```
dir(load_digits)
```

dir method gives me all the attributes and methods of "data"

```
['__annotations__',
'__call__',
'__class__',
'__closure__',
'__code__',
'__defaults__',
'__delattr__',
'__dict__',
'__dir__',
'__doc__',
'__eq__',
'__format__',
'__ge__',
'__get__',
'__getattribute__',
'__globals__',
'__gt__',
'__hash__',
'__init__',
'__init_subclass__',
'__kwdefaults__',
'__le__',
'__lt__',
'__module__',
'__name__',
'__ne__',
'__new__',
'__qualname__',
'__reduce__',
'__reduce_ex__',
'__repr__',
'__setattr__',
'__sizeof__',
'__str__',
'__subclasshook__',
'__wrapped__']
```

whereas

```
data2=load_digits()
type(data2)
```

type(data2) returns "sklearn.utils.Bunch"

```
dir(data2)
```

dir method gives all the attributes and methods of "data2".

```
['DESCR', 'data', 'feature_names', 'frame', 'images', 'target', 'target_names']
```

How can "()" cause such vast change  in dir() of same dataset?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. In your own words, what is a function? What does it mean to call a function, and what does the syntax look like for that? If you cannot confidently answer these questions, then please study a Python tutorial from start to finish; trying to do anything with machine learning is getting miles ahead of yourself, like trying to write a Shakespearean play without first knowing the alphabet. If you *can* answer such questions, then the answer to your own question should be obvious.

Comment: It's not a matter of better or worse.  It's a matter of right and wrong.  `load_digits` is a function.  Saying `load_digits` just gets you the function object.  To CALL the function , you have to write `load_digits()`.

Answer (score 2):

I strongly suggest reading carefully [what is a function in python and how to use it](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#defining-functions).

TL;DR In python variables can also be functions.

- `data=load_digits` means that `data` is an alias for `load_digits` and you can call it as it was a function `data()` so calling `data()` or `load_digits()` makes no difference.
- `data=load_digits()` means that `data` contains the result of calling the function `load_digits` and in this specific case `load_digits()` returns a `sklearn.utils.Bunch` object.